# how to apply click function on id when different id is generating dynamically for each div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending different id (#sonu) for each div Like sonu1, sonu2, sonu3 etc
so that i used this `<button id="sonu_'+p+'">Edit</button>` but i have to apply click function on this also so how to add `_'+p+'` with sonu id for click function.
this is my full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mayank" style="background:#e7e7fd; padding:20px;"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="content">
      <input type="text" id="question" style="width:30%" placeholder="enter your question"/>
      <br /><br />
      <select id="yash">
        <option value="1">radio</option>
        <option value="2">checkbox</option>
        <option value="3">Dropdown</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" id="amar"   />
      <button id="shubham">Add </button>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="rahul" ></div>
    <div id="gaurav" ></div>
    <div id="bhanu" ><select id="vicky" style="display:none;"></select></div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <button id="ram">Add in blue area</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $('#yash').change(function(){
          if($(this).val() === '3')
            $('#vicky').show();
        });
      });
      $(function(){
        var i=1;
        var p=1;
        $("#shubham").click(function(){
          var x=$("#amar").val();
          var y=$("#yash").val();
          var z=$("#amar").val();
          if(y==3){
            $('#vicky').show();
          }
          if(y==1){
            $("#rahul").append('<div ><br><input type="radio" id="aman'+i+'" >' + '<label for="aman"> '+x+'</label>'+' <button class="anshu">Delete</button> <button id="sonu_'+p+'">Edit</button> <input type="text" id="pankaj" val="12" /> <button id="kuldeep">ok</button></div>');
            i++;
            p++;
          }
          if(y==2){
            $("#gaurav").append('<input type="checkbox" >'+ x+'<button >Delete</button>');
          }
          if(y==3){
            $("#vicky").append('<option>'+z+'</option>'+ x+'<button >Delete</button>');
          }
          var m=$("#rahul").html();
          $('.anshu').click(function(){
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
          });
          $('#pankaj').hide();
          $('#kuldeep').hide();
          $('#sonu').click(function(){
            $('#pankaj').show();
            $('#kuldeep').show();
          });
          $("#kuldeep").click(function(){
            var q=$("#pankaj").val();
            $("label[for=aman]").html(q);
          });
          //$(".anshu").click(function(){
          //$(".aman").remove();
          //});
        });
        $("#ram").click(function(){
          var x=$("#rahul").html();
          var u=$("#question").val();
          $('#mayank').append('<div>'+ u +' '+ x +' </div>');
          $("#question").val('');
          $("#amar").val('');
          $("#rahul").html('');
          $('#yash').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the function to call is the same for all `#sonu...` try `$(document).on("click", "[id^='sonu']", function(){` where `^=` means "begins with".

Comment: okay let me check this

Comment: $(document).on("click", "[id^='sonu']", function(){
   
 
 $('#pankaj').show();
 $('#kuldeep').show();
        
});

Comment: i have applied this type is it right ???

Comment: Yes... Does it work or not?

Comment: no its not working

Comment: See my answer... I saw something else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Okay...

You want to attach event to appended elements...
**And** the function to call affects appended elements too.

So `$(document).on("click", "[id^='sonu']", function(){` will target your element, since the event handler is attached to `document`, a static element (not appended).

That is the same for the elements to hide/show within your function, since those are dynamically appended too... But you have to find those which are aside the clicked `sonu`. So from `sonu` parent, find them.

So try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "[id^='sonu']", function(){
  $(this).closest("div").find('.pankaj').show();
  $(this).closest("div").find('.kuldeep').show();
});
```

**AND** use a class instead of an id for those two... An id **must be unique**.
You are appending them within a loop... Meaning there can be multiple of these.

Comment: This answer is different than mine ThinkingFace

Answer (score 0):

Use a class selector and attach the event to the document.

```
$(document).on('click','.sonu-button',function(){
// do stuff here

});
```